# How to find and remove attributes in cloned item using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

I trying to clone a div content with below code.

```
var clonedItem = $("#cloneableSchoolTab").clone();
clonedItem.find(".clonableSchool").addClass("clonedSchoolTab" + schoolTabCount );
$("#clonedSchoolTabsContainer").append(clonedItem);
```

First line gets the whole target item. But, the excecution of second line, the value of `clonedItem` changed as empty array. I dont know. If i merge the first 2 line, the reasult was same as the  above code.

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="cloneableSchoolTab" class="schoolInput">
<input type="text" id="schName"/>
<input type="text" id="schDes"/>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciative.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post an example of the HTML that you're working with?

Comment: Refer this link
It well make u to get the answer
http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-clone-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post some HTML code, so that we can see what are the elements the above code is trying to clone, the only thing that I can see is if the find() method fails to find an element with class name ".clonableSchool" then it is constructing an empty jQuery object, as the jQuery doc says:

> the .find() method allows us to search
>   through the descendants of these
>   elements in the DOM tree and construct
>   a new jQuery object from the matching
>   elements

Note: I believe it should be a comment not an answer, but I don't have that privilege yet, sorry.

Comment: Thanks, man. I got the solution. What i did is, i tried to change the class name of the base `div` which i cloned. Now i tried to change the class name of input elements in the div. Its working now.